# Rails model columns and performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I am using postgresql.

I started to realise that I have created too many columns for the User model, and most of them are boolean fields.

Correct me if I am wrong, if I just update one boolean value, the whole table are being updated even though "Patch" verb is being used.

So I decided to create a specific model for some boolean columns, however, this would also trigger two queries, one for the User load and the other for the newly created model load.

My question is: Would it be better if I chop some of the columns to form a new model? Or a model with many columns just don't affect the performance of a rails app.

My main concern is the data connection speed, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding a join will be better than having two tables.

You can limit which columns are returned by [using select in ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields). If you have large text fields, but don't need them at a particular time, this can be helpful in improving performance. The impact is probably negligible with boolean columns.